# How to add files to the "StorageFolder" in design time?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

We add files to the `StorageFolder` this way:

```
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder",
    CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile.txt",
CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

But how can I add needed files in designer, there are some pictures,texts, how can I add them to use them later inside the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the file to your project and make sure that `Build Action` is set to `Content`.

Comment: oops - sorry, typo in the name. It's actually `Build Action` -you'll find it in the properties window (usually F4 if you don't see the window).

Comment: That is great man, this `Build Action` is the answer to lots of my questions